# Netezza READ sql statements form a file

Tags: sql, netezza

is there a way for Netezza to READ sql files ? In Sybase there is READ statement works like:
`READ "C:\procedure_name.sql"`. 
Im creating a script that would combine multiple scripts into one and then run it with Aginity via command line.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes," but the method depends on which interface you are using.

If you are using nzsql, then \i will do the trick:

```
[nz@netezza ~]$ cat procedure_name.sl 
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
[nz@netezza ~]$ nzsql
Welcome to nzsql, the IBM Netezza SQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help on internal slash commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> \i procedure_name.sl 
      TIMESTAMP      
---------------------
 2016-09-16 15:41:06
(1 row)
```

Note that it used to be the case that nzsql was no delivered with the windows client tools, so you had to rely on tools such as Aginity Workbench, but if you have a recent version of the Netezza client code, nzsql is now included.